# Preserving line breaks in TextField with Firebase

Tags: firebase, material-ui

If I want to save line breaks in my `<TextField>` component so I set `whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap'`.

I tried some context and printed it out to see what it would look like and I see this:

I typed in:
    asdfasdlkf

```
4444
gggg

ghhhhh
```

`"asdfasdlkf↵↵4444↵gggg↵↵ghhhhh"`

Now my question is if I save `"asdfasdlkf↵↵4444↵gggg↵↵ghhhhh"` to my Firebase data, will and read it later, will it still preserve the line breaks?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, all text is preserved exactly as you wrote it.  This should be pretty easy for you to test for yourself.

Comment: Seems like it's not actually being preserved or maybe I'm interpreting the line breaks incorrectly. I'm displaying the text and for some reason it's showing the "↵" as spaces instead

Comment: The Firebase console compresses the text for display purposes.  Try actually reading the data back out and log it.